# How to only read the second line of a text fetched from a website in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am fetching 3 line of text from a website with my vb.net application and i only want to show the second line in my my label when i press a button. The code i currently have show me all the 3 lines. How can i only display the 2nd line.

```
Dim webAddress As String = "Website"

    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim request As WebRequest
    Dim response As WebResponse
    Dim data As String = ""

    Try
        request = WebRequest.Create(webAddress)
        request.Timeout = 30000
        response = request.GetResponse()
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        data = reader.ReadToEnd
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: where's the code that sets the text property of your label? You want to use the readline method of the streamreader

Answer (score 1):

You may do this after ReadToEnd:

```
Label1.Text = Split(data, VBCrLf)(1)
```

Comment: I can't manage to make it work it return me no value my label stay blank.

Answer (score 0):

Read individual lines:

```
reader.ReadLine() 'read and discard the first line
data = reader.ReadLine() 'read the line you want
reader.ReadToEnd 'read and discard the rest
```

Comment: You don't need `reader.ReadToEnd`, so just close the reader after `data = reader.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Neolisk is right. I was just trying to resemble the behaviour of the original code.

Comment: I can't manage to make it work it return me no value my label stay blank.

Comment: @JamieOuellette: run your code in the debugger and set a breakpoint after `data = reader.ReadLine()` - then look at the value of `data` - if `data` contains the text you expected, then you have an error downstream, when you set the label's text to the value of data. If `data` does not contain the text you expected, then your web site does not provide the data in the format you expected.